# Checkboxed option in Android menu does not work

Tags: android, xml, checkbox, menuitem, android-menu

I am trying to add the checkbox to menu of my Android app. But I don't know why item with `android:checkable="true"` attribute has this square of checkbox, but behave like others items. Do I have to write something in java code? I can read the value but tapping does not changing it's value...

My menu\main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_tests"
        android:title="@string/i_want_to_test"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_translating"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="@string/i_want_to_translating"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_funmade"
        android:checkable="true"
        android:title="Enable funmade"/>

</menu>
```

Look:

[image: How menu looks]

The last option behve like other with no specified behaviour. I can tap and manu closes and state does not change. Hope you can help.

Andret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the user selects an item from the options menu (including action
>   items in the action bar), the system calls your activity's
>   onOptionsItemSelected() method.

The following code goes inside the `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method in your Activity.

**Code:**

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_settings:
            // Specify actions for the menu click
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_tests:
            // Specify actions for the menu click
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_translating:
            // Specify actions for the menu click
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_funmade:
            // Specify actions for the menu click
            if (item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                item.setChecked(true);
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

You can look at the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#checkable) about checkable menus for more details.